# how to create a desktop shortcut for brave-browser in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, shortcuts, browser, url, brave

I tried to create a desktop shortcut/starter in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which points to a URL for the Brave browser, but it seems impossible.

As a Lubuntu 22.04 LTS user I am baffled, because in Lubuntu this is very simply done by a right-click on the desktop and then it is possible to choose the listed possibility in the context menu to create a starter.
I tried this for the laptop of my girlfriend who has a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed. The desktop shortcuts that were pointing to websites and which were functioning alright before on her desktop, are all dysfunctional at this moment.
I am not sure when that happened, but I suppose that this must have happened after an upgrade that she did, with the consequence that these desktop shortcuts have stopped working.

Before, on Ubuntu, I used the method of copying another shortcut to an URL on her desktop and by then changing the content, it was possible to have it point to the right URL, but this does not work anymore, as the existing brave-browsers shortcuts are all dysfunctional now and so are their copies, of course.

On the internet several approaches to a solution for the creation of a desktop shortcut are suggested, but none of them seem to work. Especially the one suggestion that should work in my opinion, copying the ".desktop" shortcut from

```
    /usr/share/applications
```

to the desktop will not work, as Brave is not listed in

```
    /usr/share/applications
```

For the applications that are listed there that method works fine, but Brave is not listed there and I do not know why.

So my question is: **how can I create a desktop shortcut in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS that points to a website to be opened with Brave browser?**

Comment: is your brave a snap app? ( side comment, I remember being able to make shortcuts to programs on the desktop  on Windows 3.0 in 1990)

Comment: @pierrely: I am afraid that brave indeed is a snap, I now suspect that this indeed could be the culprit, as in my Lubuntu laptop I installed the Brave deb and there I do have the .desktop shortcut. When I get the chance i will try it on her machine.

Comment: workarond might be a hotkey to run brave --url if that can be done.   then again....   "brave --help
[0112/182244.612586:FATAL:chrome_main_delegate.cc(439)] execlp failed: No such file or directory (2)
/snap/brave/194/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser: line 48: 726638 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "$HERE/brave" "$@"
"

and
" brave-browser --help
brave-browser: command not found
"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it.

- You open the computer's default text editor called "text editor"
- You must make a replica of the brave browser icon, can be .png, in some place you won't ever move the icon from. I made a folder "Icons" in my pictures folder to store it there forever.
- You then type this, except the formatting forced me to separate each new line of text with an empty line, when each line should really be under the previous one:

  ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Brave Web Browser
   Exec=brave --incognito
   Icon=/home/[YOUR USERNAME]/Pictures/Icons/CustomBraveIcon.png
   Type=Application
   Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
  ```

I wrote `Icon=/home/[YOUR USERNAME]/Pictures/Icons/CustomBraveIcon.png` because this is the path to my custom icon. Use your path instead.

- You then save the file on your desktop as `brave.desktop`
- You right-click it and select "Allow Launching"
- Enjoy your browser :)